# how to upgrade app to android 6, so that it runs on API 19 - 23

Tags: android, compatibility, android-support-library, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an app, that actually runs with minimum api 19. Now I want to add to it the new runtime permissions from api 23 (android 6 marshmallow).

How do I make it possible, that runtime permissions are used if the device-api is 23 and that the old way for permissions is used if the device api is lower? Do I do that with flavors? Or appcompat-library? What is my minimum SDK and what is my target SDK?

I just need a justified answer, so that I don't go hours and days in the wrong way and notice too late, that I had to do it on another way...

Thanks a lot in advance.
Cheers, C.C.

Comment: change the targetsdk version to 22 in manifest if you don't need to handle permission stuff

Comment: there are many sample out there take look at them

Comment: keep you minSDK = 19 and set targetSDK = 23, regarding permission in pre-marshmallow devices check [this](http://androidgig.com/runtime-permission-in-pre-marshmallow/)

Answer (score 0):

Your all in one answer is

change the **targetsdk** version to **22** in **manifest** if you don't need to handle permission stuff

or for run time permission for `targetSdk 23` check this [out](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the targetSdk of your app to 23, and have v23+ of AppCompat.

You can use ContextCompat and ActivityCompat permission methods from AppCompat which will use the new permissions mechanism on Android 6 devices, and use the old way for older devices.